# Exception Handling Resumption Behaviour

Tags: java, exception, try-catch-finally

new to StackOverFlow and fairly new to Java. Been programming in C prior to this and am trying to get the foundations of Java.

Just a bit confused about the following code:

```
public class Exercise5 {
private static int[] ia = new int[3];
static int x = 5;   
public static void main(String[] args) {
    while(true) {
        try {
            ia[x] = 1;
            System.out.println(ia[x]);
            break;  
        } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.err.println(
                "Caught ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException");
                e.printStackTrace();
            x--;
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Are we done yet?");     
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Now, we're done.");
}
```

}

I am still trying to get my head around the try,catch and finally blocks. What I do not understand is in this code the program only runs until the first instance that a non exception occurs happens and then it exits the while loop.

My understanding is that the while loop will run until you run out of memory so can someone please explain how the code exits the while loop on the first instance of non exception.

Thank you!

Marco

Comment: Sorry I just realised there was a break keyword. But to clarify, the finally block will be executed no matter how we exit the try block like in this example in which we broke out of the try block as well as the while loop?

Comment: `finally` block is always run, unless you execute `System.exit()` in `try/catch` block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `x` is equals to 5 and then program goes to the `while` loop. Since 5 is greater than the size of the array, it will give exception and go to the exception block. Here, `x` will be decreased and run into the `while` loop again. Until `x` reaches to 2, there is no exception anymore; therefore, it can reach the `break` line. So, program can exit the `while` loop and finish

Comment: This is correct. The loop iterates only if there is an exception. And every exception will decrement the index of X until no exception occurs and the "break" line is reached which exits the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

`try{}`

Executes the code until an Exception is occured

`catch(ExceptionType e){}`

if thrown exception meets the excetpion type mentioned , following block gets executed along with exception supplied, here as `e`

`finally{}`

Executes irrespective of exception(s) thrown

Answer (score 0):

You created an array with size of 3, an variable x with value of 5. So in first iteration you will see `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, but in `catch` block `x` is decremented. So we go again, now `x` is 4, and than 3 and finally it is 2. Now you will no see any exceptions and program is done.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly **Try will get executed if it is exceuted without exception then it will break in just one iteration and Finally will be executed**.

**If an exception occurs it will go in catch block and Then in finally**.

**It will reiterate the loop according to above given behaviour**..Feel free to ask for further clarifiactions.